# Is there any alternative way for injecting our modules as dependencies while creating a module?

Tags: angularjs

while creating  a module we inject our dependencies after our modulename in[].Here am asking is there any possible way to inject our modules other than this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add dependencies by using the `requires` array:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.requires.push('newDependency');
```

Comment: where we need to define the requires array?

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to it. The only way is this. 
However you can use `$inject` when injecting controller dependencies.
See here : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di